# Can I use a JdbcTemplate to process in parallel without loading everything into memory?

Tags: java, jdbctemplate

I've got a non-spring app that's using `JdbcTemplate`.  We have a requirement to load all the data of a large table.  Each row stores an id.  Using this id, we want to send a notification to a mobile app.  We know how to do this technically, but the table has so much data, java is getting out of memory errors.  I saw that a `RowCallbackHandler` could prevent the out of memory errors, but we'd like this to run in parallel, so the notifications go out as fast as possible.  Is there a way to get the best of both worlds?

I was going to just spawn like 10 threads and give each thread a chunk of the table to scan through.  Is there a better way?

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](http://knes1.github.io/blog/2015/2015-10-19-streaming-mysql-results-using-java8-streams-and-spring-data.html)?

Comment: [This article](https://blog.apnic.net/2015/08/05/using-the-java-8-stream-api-with-springs-jdbctemplate/) showcases how streaming via JDBCTemplate can be achieved